# Frame capture in Xcode fails

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es-2.0

I am using Xcode 4.5.1 and testing on an iPhone5 with iOS6.

I was using the frame capture function without problem, but suddenly it stopped working.
When I press the frame capture button, it seems the frame is captured, and the phone switches to a blank screen, only to suddenly switch back to the application screen, and the application keeps running. I can still debug and pause the application, but there's no way to get the frame capture. I don't see any errors in the console either.

The reason it stopped working is this piece of code. This code is supposed to render something to a rendertexture, but the rendertexture seems blank. I wanted to use the frame capture function to find out what's wrong, but the code itself won't let me capture... :(

Any idea why?

```
// ------------- init function -----------------
// Create the framebuffer and bind it
glGenFramebuffers(1, &g_framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, g_framebuffer);
//Create the destination texture, and attach it to the framebuffer’s color attachment point.
glGenTextures(1, &g_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,  w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texture, 0);    
//Test the framebuffer for completeness
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) ;
if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
} else {
    NSLog(@"SkyPlugin initialized");
}


// ----------------- on update  ------------------
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &oldFBO);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, oldViewPort);
// set the framebuffer and clear
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, g_framebuffer);
glViewport(0, 0, 32, 32);
//glClearColor(0.9f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
// Set shader   
glUseProgram(m_program);
// do some glEnableVertexAttribArray
// ...
// texture setting
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glUniform1i(m_uniform, 0);
ResourceManager* resourceManager = ResourceManager::GetInstance();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture[0]);
// ----------- Draw -----------
// Draws a full-screen quad to copy textures
static const vertexDataUV quad[] = {
    {/*v:*/{-1.f,-1.f,0}, /*t:*/{0,0}},
    {/*v:*/{-1.f,1,0}, /*t:*/{0,1}},
    {/*v:*/{1,-1.f,0}, /*t:*/{1,0}},
    {/*v:*/{1,1,0}, /*t:*/{1,1}}
};
static const GLubyte indeces[] = {0,2,1,3};
glVertexAttribPointer(m_posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, sizeof(vertexDataUV), &quad[0].vertex);
glVertexAttribPointer(m_texCoordAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, sizeof(vertexDataUV), &quad[0].uv);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indeces);
// ------------ End
// go back to the main framebuffer!
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, oldFBO);
glViewport(oldViewPort[0], oldViewPort[1], oldViewPort[2], oldViewPort[3]);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
```

**Edit: (2012/October/28)**

I found out why the above code was not working. I forgot to bind a render buffer! The code below works, but still the frame capture fails when this code is active...

On init,

// Create the renderbuffer and bind it
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &g_renderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, g_renderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8_OES, w, h);

```
// Create the framebuffer and bind it
glGenFramebuffers(1, &g_framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, g_framebuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                          GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                          GL_RENDERBUFFER, g_renderbuffer);
//Create the destination texture, and attach it to the framebuffer’s color attachment point.
glGenTextures(1, &g_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,  w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texture, 0);
```

On update,

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_RENDERBUFFER_BINDING, &oldRBO);
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &oldFBO);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, oldViewPort);

// set the framebuffer and clear
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, g_framebuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, g_renderbuffer);
glViewport(0, 0, 32, 32);

// ... draw stuff ...
```

End of update,

```
// go back to the main framebuffer!
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, oldFBO);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, oldRBO);
```

Comment: We have exactly the same problem. No idea what's the cause :(

Comment: The only log I could get so far is this:
`
    10/28/12 7:02:19.818 PM Xcode[5371]: [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/GPUDebuggeriOSSupport/GPUDebuggeriOSSupport-51.8/GPUiOSReplayController.m:127
    Details:  replayer terminated incorrectly
    Object:   <GPUiOSReplayController: 0x402e7c520>
    Method:   -_handleGuestAppStatusChangeNotification:
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40030a220>{name = (null), num = 1}
    Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it was a bug of Xcode. 
The latest version, Xcode 4.5.2 lets me capture the frame :)

After I capture the frame, I get an error in this part of the code:

```
// ... draw stuff ...
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glUniform1i(MY_TEXTURE, 0);
```

On the glUniform1i I get this error: "The specified operation is invalid for the current OpenGL state".

No idea why I get this error (the rendering it's working), but I suspect this error may be the reason why I wasn't able to capture a frame in the previous version of Xcode...

Comment: The reason for the error is that I was setting a uniform (MY_TEXTURE) not defined in the shader (the name of the sampler was different). I should try with Xcode 4.5.1 again without the error and see if capture works... but who's gonna be using an older version of Xcode anyway? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen very similar behavior, and while it was a bit erratic, it did seem to be related to memory usage.  Usually when it failed, the replay application seemed to be running out of memory (I'd see a memory warning in the console when it failed).

Switching to a device with more memory fixed it (iPad 4 from iPad 3), but I also was able to occasionally work around it by reducing the amount of texture memory used -- skipping setting the top mipmap for all my textures would usually free up enough.